# Using a script to run 2 programs, both with blocking functions

Tags: c++, shell

I'm trying to run 2 C++ programs simultaneously. Both programs make use of `inotify` to each watch a folder for file creation, then handle the events (in a different manner) respectively. The programs also run indefinitely so they are forever watching their respective folders for new files.

I have a shell script that simply does the following:

```
./program1 -i input_file -o output_file
./program2 -i input_file -o output_file
```

I'm worried that because `program1` is blocking and runs indefinitely, `program2` will never get to execute. Is this the case? How should I work around this then?

Will `./program1 -i input_file -o output_file & ./program2 -i input_file -o output_file` work?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking"? It will but you'll have to insert a newline after '&'.

Comment: @bipil Actually you don't need a newline there but you should put one anyway to make it easier to read.

Comment: Yes, you can use `&` to make a program run in the background i.e. the shell will not wait for it to finish before running the next command. Was that the whole question?

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone.